# Using parts of Aurelia

Tags: binding, aurelia

Is it possible to use some parts of the Aurelia framework? Specifically the binding system. I want to make a website (not an SPA) and want to use the binding system in Aurelia and the fetch client. Is it feasible or are there other better alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is entirely possible to only use parts of the Aurelia system as it is very modular in nature, take a look at: http://patrickwalters.net/enhance-an-existing-page-with-aurelia/ for an example of how to enhance an existing page.

But essentially you just need to include the Aurelia libraries into the existing page/application for bootstrapping and then selectively use the parts of Aurelia that suits your needs.

Comment: the key is to only use the libraries you want, and not simply pull in `aurelia-framework`.